# PHP MySQL Encoding Bug?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

Heres my problem. I have a mysql table called quotes. In one of the rows, a quote contains the folloqing characters

```
‘ and ’
```

Now the row collation is **utf8__unicode__ci**

When using MySQL Query Browser and PHPMyAdmin to retrive the rows the quotes come out as intended. How ever when i retrive them from the database using PHP and display them on the screen they come out as boxes

```
� and �
```

My html page has UTF-8 encoding, and all the UTF-8 encoding options are set in php:

```
/* Set UTF-8 settings */
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');

/* Set ICONV ini settings */
ini_set('iconv.input_encoding', 'UTF-8');
ini_set('iconv.output_encoding', 'UTF-8');
ini_set('iconv.internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');

/* Set ICONV function settings */
iconv_set_encoding('input_encoding', 'UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding('output_encoding', 'UTF-8');
iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

It seems to me that it should work. But it doesnt :S can anyone shed some light onto this please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to set UTF-8 as the chosen charset on your MySQL connection. If you are using the mysqli PHP driver this means something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: the query is SET NAMES 'utf8'

Comment: I think it's SET CHARACTER SET that's doing it for him, actually.  SET NAMES is to do with table/column/etc identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

@Joakim, thanks so much for setting me in the right direction. I couldnt use your exact code because im using a custom database driver and it works using the old mysql commands not the mysqli class. I tried using mysql_set_charset() but my php version didnt support it (still php 5 tho).

this is the solution i used:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->connection);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $this->connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your collation isn't helping you; it's just determining sort order.  You need the default character set to be utf-8, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `id` int not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(50)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

You should be able to address this with:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Only gotcha is that sometimes your indexes would be too long if they're in utf-8.

Comment: @chaos i just tried that. it still doesnt work. Its something to do with PHP as both MySQL Query Browser and PHPMyAdmin show the quotes correctly.

Comment: Erm... what's your HTTP document encoding?  View > Character Encoding in Firefox.

Comment: When you're displaying your database content via your own PHP, I mean; it's certainly utf-8 in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Well, let's not wait for feedback: I'm guessing you'll find it to be ISO-8859-1, which means you need to tell it to be utf-8.  My favored method is: header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  Note the lack of quotes around utf-8; that's a browser compat thing.

Comment: It turns out it was the charset of my MySQL connection. It was latin1 instead of utf8.

Comment: Hunh.  Neat.  Wonder why I never had that problem.  Different defaults in my versions/installs, I suppose.